# Indefinite Integral Constant Multiple Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I am looking at the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287079) from Math Exchange.

In the post guest196883 writes

> The rule stated only applies for definite integrals. That is:
>   $$\int_a^b\alpha f\,dx = \alpha \int_a^bf \,dx$$

Does this mean it is NOT true in general for indefinite integrals? That is:

$$\int\alpha f\,dx = \alpha \int f \,dx$$

There was a short discussion in the comments of the post on this but I don't believe it was ever fully addressed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remember that both sides also have an arbitrary constant of integration.

Comment: Agreed, duplicate, sorry! Thanks for the link